# Install apk programmatically that is working for Android 11 and below

Tags: android

I am still new to Android development. I am trying a few sets of codes now just to update or install apk programmatically. And as expected I can't make them work for me, since I really have very limited knowledge yet. The main issues I get are mostly about the permission requests. As of the moment, I am working on this code I found on the internet:

```
public class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
private Context context;
public void setContext(Context contextf){
    context = contextf;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        String PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/Download/";
        File file = new File(PATH);
        file.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(file, "update.apk");
        if(outputFile.exists()){
            outputFile.delete();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
        context.startActivity(intent);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        MVPX.log("Update error! " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Then use it in my MainActivity like so:

```
UpdateApp atualizaApp = new UpdateApp();
atualizaApp.setContext(getApplicationContext());
atualizaApp.execute("https://sample.com/app-debug.apk");
```

In my manifest file I included these requests just to make sure:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

But for some reason I always get this error:

```
Update error! /mnt/sdcard/Download/update.apk: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Please help me with this, I really need to make it work for my project. If you have a better and more direct solution than the approach I provided above it will be a great help. But if you can provide me with proper permission handling to make the given code work for Android 11 and below, that's much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the neccesary permissions before you start to download.

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> storagePermission;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    storagePermission = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
                result -> {
                    if (result) checkAndUpdate();
                });
    }

private void checkAndUpdate() {
        if (hasStoragePermission()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                if (getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
                    // Continue to download
                } else {
                    // Ask unknown resources permission
                    requestUnknownSourcesPermission();
                }
            } else {
                // Continue to download
            }
        } else {
            // Ask storage permission
            storagePermission.launch(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void requestUnknownSourcesPermission() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES)
                .setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName())));
        installPermission.launch(intent);
    }

    private boolean hasStoragePermission(){
      return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. EACCES (Permission denied).

Maybe I made a mistake about where to place your code. I this inside onCreate:

`ActivityResultLauncher<String> storagePermission = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
                result -> {
                    if (result) checkAndUpdate();
                });`

While the methods are on your code, I place them outside or below onCreate.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer now, now you can access storagePermission globally in that activity

Answer (score 0):

To avoid requiring any permissions, you should store the APK in app's private folders, like cache folder.